# How to fetch the list of workflows for a GitHub private repository?

Tags: api, github, github-actions

Following this documentation: https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/actions#list-repository-workflows

Fetching `/repos/{owner}/{repo}/actions/workflows` should return the list of all workflows for a repository. This works fine for public repositories.

But, I couldn't figure out how to do it for private repositories, there is no `token` header or anything similar that might be used for authentication.

Does anyone have an example for private repositories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@VonC answer's explains how to do it using Basic Auth. The below answer explains how to do it using the `token` Authorization header and Node.js.

```
const response = await fetch(GITHUB_API_LIST_PROJECT_WORKFLOWS, {
  headers: {
    Authorization: `token ${process.env.GITHUB_TOKEN}`,
  },
});
```

Where `GITHUB_API_LIST_PROJECT_WORKFLOWS` is a token generated at https://github.com/settings/tokens that contains full `repo` and `workflow` scopes.

Where `GITHUB_API_LIST_PROJECT_WORKFLOWS` is a url of the form `/repos/{owner}/{repo}/actions/workflows`, as described in https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/actions#list-repository-workflows.

Comment: It's my fault, I hadn't specified it at all!

Answer (score 3):

The "If the repository is private you must use an access token with the repo scope" part of the documentation should refer to "[Getting started with the REST API / Using personal access tokens](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/guides/getting-started-with-the-rest-api#using-personal-access-tokens)"

> The easiest and best way to authenticate with the GitHub API is by using Basic Authentication via [OAuth tokens](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/overview/other-authentication-methods#via-oauth-and-personal-access-tokens).
> OAuth tokens include [personal access tokens](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/articles/creating-an-access-token-for-command-line-use).

Example:

```sh
curl -i -u username:$token https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/actions/workflows
```

Comment: I tried to use this solution and couldn't make it work (using node.js). But I don't know for sure that how I did was the right way to do it. Instead, I used a similar approach with `token` authorization header, which proved to work perfectly.