# How to use Github API to revoke OAuth authentication?

Tags: node.js, github, oauth, netlify-function

Here is the code I'm using, but I keep getting a 403 error in response.

```
let username = "CLIENT_ID_GOES_HERE";
let password = "SECRET_GOES_HERE";
let basicAuth = Buffer.from(`${username}:${password}`).toString('base64');

try {
    response = await axios.delete(`https://github.com/applications/${clientId}/grant`, 
    {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Basic ${basicAuth}`,
            'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.v3+json',
        },
        data: {
            access_token: token
        }
    });
} catch (e) {
    return {
        statusCode: 502,
        body: JSON.stringify(e)
    }
}
```

I've verified that the client ID, secret and token are all correct. The token I'm using is the one that is returned by github upon authenticating.

Comment: From what i can see in the docs the authorization header type is Token not basic

Comment: Yup I saw that too, but if you read the description of the endpoint, it says that Basic authentication is required. So it's really confusing. I'll try again with the Token type.

Comment: GH's  implementation of Basic Auth isn't RFC 2617-compliant, as noted by their [doc](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/other-authentication-methods#basic-authentication). `Authorization: token...` isn't Basic Auth at all as defined by the RFC, it's a GH-custom thing. GH docs calling this 'Basic Auth' is a doc bug.

Answer (score 1):

Check if, as [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65458186/6309), a token authorization header would work better:

```
Authorization: `token ${process.env.GITHUB_TOKEN}`,
```

Comment: I've used this but got the same 403 error. Is this supposed to be the token that github returns when you first authenticate?

Comment: @Dominique It should be your PAT ([Personal Access Token](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token))

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. First, I had to modify my axios request to be able to see the full error message. Inside the 'catch' part of a try-catch, I was able to take a look at the value of `error.response.data`.

The error I was getting was "Cookies must be enabled to use github".

After some Googling, someone with the same error commented that they had to use the host `api.github.com`.  Turns out that I was using `github.com`. Once I changed this, the error went away.